# Selecting the list item only once in a list view in android

Tags: android, listview, selection

Hi Every one I'm facing with a problem in android what i need is I'm having a list view in my Activity which is dynamically set with the values from database, If i select a particular item in the list view any action should not be occur and it should be get highlighted.Now I'm having a button(Submit) in the same Activity when ever i click the button the item in the list view value should be displayed in the second activity in a text view.Please help me in solving this

I have created the list view using array adapter 
What i need is user should select a name from the list view and click on submit button so that his name should be displayed in the next activity.
Thanks in advance

```
public class Unitselctn extends Activity{
Button b1;
LinearLayout ll1;
ListView lv;
Cursor c;
SQLiteDatabase db;
Spinner sp1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.selection);

    sp1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> unt= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Units,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    unt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    sp1.setAdapter(unt);
    //sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
    lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    //create database if not already exist
       db= openOrCreateDatabase("Hangman", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       //create new table if not already exist
       db.execSQL("create table if not exists user_reg(name varchar not null, phnum number not null,email varchar not null)");
       displayData();
```

}
    public void onNew(View v){

```
            insertData();
}
public void insertData(){
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Button1",5000).show();
            AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ll1=new LinearLayout(this);
            ll1.setOrientation(1);
            final EditText name= new EditText(this);
            final EditText phno= new EditText(this);
            final EditText email= new EditText(this);
            ll1.addView(name);
            ll1.addView(phno);
            ll1.addView(email);
            name.setHint("UserName");
            phno.setHint("Mobile No");
            email.setHint("Email-id");
            adb.setTitle("Registration");
            adb.setView(ll1);

            adb.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String nme=name.getText().toString();
                        String phn=phno.getText().toString();
                        String mail=email.getText().toString();
                        name.setText("");
                        phno.setText("");
                        email.setText("");

                         db.execSQL("insert into user_reg values('"+nme+"','"+phn+"','"+mail+"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered Successfully",5000).show();
                        displayData();
                }
            }); 
                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                adb.show();

}

public void  displayData(){
    List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Hangman",MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    c=db.rawQuery("select name from user_reg", null);
    if(c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String usr=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            array.add(usr);
        }while(c.moveToNext());
 }
ArrayAdapter<String> adptr= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.member_name,array);
lv.setAdapter(adptr);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adptr[pos], 5000).show();
    }
});
adptr.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Try to change background of selected item in adapter and store selected item position in local variable now whenever submit button clicked try to get position of selected item from local variable and pass as intent String Extra get in another activity from intent and shown in TextView.

Comment: I have changed the background of the selected item, but i don't know how to store the selected item position in local variable.Please help me with some code snippets.

Comment: take local int variable in your activity and when you change selected item background store position in this variable and try get from this variable when submit button click is simple.

Comment: Why not just open the second activity when the user clicks the item? Most users do not want to click twice if one would do.

Answer (score 0):

1.have on arraylist add the item that get clicked to it 
2.pass condition

```
if(yourArrayList.contains(item)){
return true;
}else
{
return false;
}
```

3.Set allItemareClickble to false

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Now I can't post code, Just an Idea.

1. Create a variable SelectedItem;
2. Inside `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { }` assign the value of the selected list item to the variable(SelectedItem).
3. Inside OnClickListener method of the button Send this variable(SelectedItem) to the next activity using Intent.